# Visual Studio 2015 Report Viewer Error

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Why? is that it has an error when I drag the report viewer

Comment: Looks like you could possibly have a duplicate of some kind, possibly a duplicate report viewer. Check to see if you have any duplicates in your project.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error (not a picture)** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38323050-749f-4616-b513-b6a410e56d78/visual-studio2012-prof-reporting-windows-forms?forum=clr